# java program runs both the if and the else statemets

Tags: java

I am quiet a newbie when it comes to programming and I am trying to write something similar to a chess program. Here is the part of code with which I am having trouble:

```
if (chosenCollumn == tempCollumn && ((chosenRow == tempRow + 1) || (chosenRow == tempRow + 2))){
        board[chosenRow][chosenCollumn ] = movingPiece;
        board[tempRow][tempCollumn] = null;
}
else {
        System.out.println("invalid move");
}
```

The problem is that the program runs both the if statement AND the else statement. It moves the piece to a new place and "removes" it from the previous place. And after that it stil prints "invalid move". Now I'm not an expert, but this shouldnt be possible right? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you call the code multiple times?

Comment: Sounds like that block of code runs more than once, with your chosen/temp values changing in the meantime

Comment: I see... Well, I am iterating throught the collumns an rows with the help of two for loops so that might be the reason. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?  If not, I would recommend learning the basics of that via a quick Google search.  Stepping through the code line-by-line, in my opinion, is a great tool for learning a new language.

Comment: Most likely your check is executed twice on moving a piece. But as you receive the error in parallel to the correct execution, some code that updates your variables must have been executed in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `if-else` structure, the JVM will not execute both the if and the else statements.

It seems like you watched over something.

I can think of 2 Scenarios

- You run the code multiple times and the condition is `true` once(`if` gets executed) and `false` the other time(`else` gets executed) (this seems to be it, see the comments)
- The code is executed once but you have some code at another point of your program that does the same thing and makes you think that both statements are executed.

In any case, debugging would help :)

Comment: The first scenario seems to be the case. After looking through the comments, I realized that the program runs the if statement several times in order to find the right collumn and the right row.

Comment: I wrote that in my answer: `this seems to be it, see the comments`

Comment: Yes  I think the same. Maybe the problem is the code around the if. It doesn't matter where you put the block because maybe it's somewhere else where the problem really is. Check the callers.